# Processing CloudFront-logs with Elastic MapReduce (PIG)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-cloudfront, apache-pig

I would like to process the access-logs that Amazon CloudFront creates with Amazon Elastic MapReduce.

I just need some simple stats on how many times different files has been loaded from cloudfront so i thought i should just write a simple PIG-script for this.

The first problem i have is that cloudfront write the logs gzipped and as far as i know i can't read .gz in pig?

Any suggestions on how i should do this? I'm very new to elastic mapreduce so any hints on how to structure this kind of job is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this works by default. No need to unzip the logs before processing them. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Qloudstat](http://qloudstat.com). We will offer statistics of CloudFront access logs as a service.